# How to have shiny dashboard box fill the entire width of my dashbaord

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm struggling to get my dashboard layout to be formatted in a way that looks good.

I have a box that is not the full width of my dashboard and the plot that is inside of it is actually wider and sticks out of it. (although I do believe once I make a plotly graph it will work fine).

I'm using fillRow but it does not fill the entire row and only half of the page.

Here is my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Overview",tabName = "Overview", icon = icon("tachometer-alt")),
      menuItem("Assessments",tabName = "Assessments", icon = icon("list"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "Overview",
              # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
              fluidRow(
                valueBoxOutput("rate"),
                valueBoxOutput("count"),
                valueBoxOutput("users"),
              ),
              fluidRow(  
                box(title = "Title",
                    status = "primary",
                ),
                
                box(align = "center",
                    title = "Select Inputs",status = "warning", solidHeader = F,
                    selectInput("dropdown1", "Select Drilldown:", c(50,100,200)))
              ),
              fillRow(width = "100%",
                       box(
                         title = "Graph 1", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                         plotOutput("plot1", height = "50vh", width = "100vh")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Assessments",
              h2("Assessmnents tab content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$dropdown1)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$instructions <- renderText("Company Name")
  
  output$rate <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = 130,
      subtitle = "Overview 1",
      icon = icon("area-chart"),
      color =  "aqua"
    )
  })
  
  output$count <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = 120,
      subtitle = "Overview 2",
      icon = icon("download"),
      color = "red"
    )
  })
  
  output$users <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = 85,
      subtitle = "Overview 3",
      icon = icon("users"),
      color = "purple"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And a screen shot

[image]

My desired goal would be something like this

[image]

Is there any reccomended resources I can read to get better at shiny dashboard layouts and controlling the view?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `width = 12` in the `box` function. Additionally, to make sure the plot is always using the entire width of the box use `width = "100%"` in  `plotOutput`.

```R
fillRow(
  box(
    width = 12, 
    title = "Graph 1", 
    status = "primary", 
    solidHeader = TRUE, 
    plotOutput(
      "plot1", 
      height = "50vh", 
      width = "100%")
  )
)
```

The [Shiny Dashboard](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/index.html) documentation is a good place to start learning the structure, appearance, and behavior of Shiny Dashboard. You can also get some extra functionality by using [shinydashboardPlus](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/). Finally, [shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets) provides a great selection of custom widgets with an improved visual look.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about layout. Here I provide shinydashboard skeleton and some explanation that might suits your problem'. You can put this code inside `dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "Overview",...)))`

```
fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4,valueBoxOutput(width = 12,"blue_value_box")) ,
    column(width = 4,valueBoxOutput(width = 12,"red_value_box")) ,
    column(width = 4,valueBoxOutput(width = 12,"purple_value_box"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,box(width = 12,"Title")),
    column(width = 6,box(width = 12,"Select Inputs",
                         selectInput("someinputhere")))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12,
           box(width = 12,plotOutput("histogramofdata"))
    )
  )
)
```

First of all the column is not necessary for your case, its just very helpful to explain shiny layout. Keep in mind shiny have a strict width value, 12 maximum. If you define width in something like box or `column()`, everything inside that will follow its width rather than global width. For example in my example, i put `valueboxoutput()` inside column(). you can see that the column has width = 4 and the valueboxoutput has 12. The `column()` will follow the page width and the valuebox will follow column width. I don't know if this is the best practice but i like to use `fluidrow()` to make a separation by row between an shiny object.

[image]

For more clearer example, in the image above, i highlighted the `fluidrow()` in red and blue for `column()`.